# React JS Redirect Upon Sign in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I need my user to be redirected upon success. What I have now does not redirect but will present the success pop up message at the end of the form.

JSX File

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState('');


  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

  const login = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:5000/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.message) {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.message);
          
        } else {
          setLoginStatus(response.data.username);
          return <Navigate to="/admin/home" />;

        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error logging in:', error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/check-session')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.loggedIn) {
          return <Navigate to="/admin/home" />;

           // Redirect to /admin/home if already logged in
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error checking session:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='Login-page'>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={login}>

        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-outline-primary'>
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
      {loginStatus && <p>{loginStatus}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Server.js (Express file)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');




// Middleware
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000', // Replace with your frontend application's URL
  methods: ["GET","POST","PUT", "DELETE"],
  credentials: true, // Allow credentials (cookies)
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.json()); // Parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use(morgan('dev')); // Use Morgan for logging HTTP requests

// Session setup
/* Set Cookie Settings */
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secretKey123',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: false, // Set this to true if you use HTTPS
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
    },
  })
);


// Routes


app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  connection.query(
    'SELECT * FROM admin_users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?',
    [username, password],
    (error, results, fields) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error executing MySQL query: ' + error.stack);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
      }

      if (results.length > 0) {
        req.session.username = username; // Set session variable to the username
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Login successful' });
      } else {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password' });
      }
    }
  );
});

app.get('/check-session', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.username) {
    res.json({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.username });
  } else {
    res.json({ loggedIn: false });
  }
});


app.post('/check-session', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session)
  if (req.session.isLoggedIn) {
    res.json({ isLoggedIn: true });
  } else {
    res.json({ isLoggedIn: false });
  }
});

app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy((error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error destroying session:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }

    res.clearCookie('userId'); // Clear the session cookie
    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Logout successful' });
  });
});


  

// Start the server
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 5000');
});
```

I have tried using Navigate to redirect but it does nothing. At this point anything would help. Ive tried following a Youtube guide but I ran into an issue with getting the session started. Now I have the session started but it fails to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true what @Maulik said you should use the `navigate` instance of `useNavigate` instead of `<Navigate to="/admin/home" />`.

You need to add Content-type header to Axios post. Additionally, axios already has error handling, so failed responses from your API will fall directly into the catch block. So,

```
const login = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost:5000/login",
      {
        username: username,
        password: password,
      },
      {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      setLoginStatus(response.data.username);
      navigate("/admin/home", { replace: true });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      error?.response
        ? setLoginStatus(error.response.data.message)
        : setLoginStatus("No server response..");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't Navigate like this in the latest version of react-router-dom (v6).

You have to follow these steps:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

Now in the function, you have to create instance of it in the following way.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

and, now you can redirect using this navigate.

Just replace your `return <Navigate to="/admin/home" />`
with the `navigate("/admin/home)`

You can refer this for more info: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're checking first for "response.data.message"

```
if (response.data.message) {
      setLoginStatus(response.data.message);
      
    }
```

And if there is a message, you just set the login status and do nothing!

When looking to Backend code, you're always returning a message either it is a valid user/password or not.

```
if (results.length > 0) {
    req.session.username = username; // Set session variable to the username
    res.json({ success: true, message: 'Login successful' });
  } else {
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password' });
  }
```

This is why it does nothing. You need to check for something unique, "success" for example and also check that there is no "error", then redirect.